# Using C# application with Mysql Database on Another Computer

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-string

I have made a C# application MySql Database attached I am going to use the Application on a different Computer. According to my Logic. The Mysql database is running on the localhost server of my first PC and I think that the localhost of the other PC will be different. So,My application Won't connect to the server - It's my Idea which may be wrong.

I have the following Questions :-

1.

How do I make a Mysql local server that will even work on another PC.

2.

Do I have to Install MySql on other PC ? If yes How can i include mysql setup in the Setup Wizard of my app.

3.

Do I have to make changes In the Code (Connection or anything).

Please Give any extra suggestion if you have about this.

Answer (score 1):

- You do not need to install mySQL on the computer that will have the app. that defeats the purpose of having a SQL Server
- You will only need to change the connection string so instead of connecting to Localhost or 127.0.0.1 you will use the ip address of the machine that has the server installed. [Connection Strings](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-string.html)
- I suggest you do some reading about networking, design patterns, and SQL or you risk building a very insecure application.

Comment: In the second point you said " you will use the ip address of the machine that has the server installed" does it mean my first computer on which I make the app??